# Finding rectangular polygons in a multipolygon

Tags: qgis, postgis, polygon, multi-polygon, rectangle

I'm trying to do some analysis that requires finding rectangular gardens of a certain size. At present, I only have access to a data set of property extents with buildings punched out with the assumption that the remainder is the garden.

I have used [this excellent answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299514/qgis-tool-to-identify-polygons-that-can-fit-a-certain-sized-square-within-the-po) to identify geometries that could contain the rectangle conforming to the dimensions I am interested in. I end up with a result set as follows:-

[image]

I now want to select the gardens that will be rectangular and work out their approximate dimensions. I've highlighted some example candidates. The problem is that the property extent polygon often stretches round the building making this hard to do. I'm only really looking for an approximation at this stage.

I implemented a version of the largest inscribed rectangle [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70362355/finding-largest-inscribed-rectangle-in-polygon) but this does not cope with the building hole. It also included a conversion to/from numpy and a set of geometry rotations which lost precision.

Is there another approach I could take? I am happy to use other approaches including Postgis

Comment: You could get the `points of inaccessibility` of the selected polygons and using the distance between the POI and the polygon border assume square gardens, resulting in `(distance*2)*(distance*2)` as your approximated area.

Comment: Thanks but, I am trying to find rectangular gardens. Not assume them.

Comment: Ah, I read it in the first place you already knew how to select the rectangular polygons.

Comment: Compare the `ST_ConvexHull` of each property geometry to its `ST_OrientedEnvelope` ; e.g..their `ST_Area` should align as much as possible to be considered rectangular.

Comment: I'd looked at that the problem is the shapes that are basically two rectangles connected by a sliver. As you can see in the yellow selected items. I need a way of isolating the rectangle containing the computed negative bounding box.

Comment: Actually this has given me an idea. If I compute an interior bounds for each shape of -2 metres. Then use your approach to work out if it is a rectangle. If it is then if its dimensions +2 on either side match my requirements I should have a fit.

Comment: Not sure I get the problem. Can you share the data seen in the image above?

Comment: I'm not sure which bit or bits of the garden you are interested in - maybe add another screenshot or two to your question?

Comment: If you look at the screenshot above you will see yellow highlighted gardens with a small bounding box within. I want the rectangle that this bounding box lies with. Most houses have a front and back garden as can be seen by the shapes having a hole. The complication is the area that connects front and back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a working solution which is good enough for the purposes of my analysis. It is not perfect but may help someone else. I've created a processing model in QGIS that works through the following steps:-

- for each land parcel create a bounding box of size -(the hypotenuse of the rectangle I'm trying to fit)
- select all land parcels that contain a bounding box of non-zero area
- create a bounding box of -2 metres for these (this is the crude bit but in the UK it removes many of the side passages down a house)
- split this bounding box into single part geometries
- create an orientated minimum bounding box for each
- run overlap analysis between the bounding box and OMBB
- select anything with overlap > 96% (broadly rectangular)
- work out the length/width of each selected OMBB
- add 4m to length and width

In the image below the yellow highlights are gardens that will contain my rectangle and the beige ones are broadly rectangular.

[image]